# How to use two T findOne(ID id) in CrudRepository?

Tags: repository, persistence, spring-data-jpa

I have a Entity with two id as below:

```
public class Myset {
    private Long id
    private String secernId;
}
```

I defined interface so that I can use findOne(Long id), but I also want use findOne(String secernId), how can I do? is this possible?

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<Myset, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CrudRepository has the findOne method defined as:

```
T findOne(ID primaryKey);
```

You have specified Long as the second generig parameter to the extended CrudRepository meaning the extended findOne would actually be like

```
Myset findOne(Long primaryKey);
```

So you will not get findOne(String secernId) from it.

What you can do is define a new method in your interface like:

```
public Myset findBySecernId(String secernId);
```

ALternatively, if you would really like your method to be named findOne, you could implement it via custom repository implementation. But honestly, I believe this is just an overhead for this simple operation.